# How to fix KeyError when accessing 'DJANGO_DEBUG' variable

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I am getting following error while executing migrate command: `python manage.py migrate`.

```
File "/Users/Jhon/djangowww/project/app/blog/settings.py", line 29, in <module>
DEBUG = os.environ['DJANGO_DEBUG'] == 'True'
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DJANGO_DEBUG'
```

How can recover from this issue?

Comment: add the key to your environment variables?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyError` means that the `DJANGO_DEBUG` envariable was not set. To avoid it you can either call `get()` on the [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) mapping or use the [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) function:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == 'True'
```

or

```
DEBUG = os.getenv('DJANGO_DEBUG') == 'True'
```